# Installing Boost 1.59.0 Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost

I'm trying to install Boost 1.59.0 on Ubuntu, I cannot install it from `apt-get` because that contains an older version.

I'm cloning the `modular-boost` repo and I'm trying to build it with the following command:

```
$./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local
$./b2 headers
```

Finally I'm trying to confirm that that boost was installed with this simple c file

```
#include <boost/version.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
      std::cout << "Boost version: " 
                  << BOOST_VERSION / 100000
                            << "." 
                                      << BOOST_VERSION / 100 % 1000
                                                << "." 
                                                          << BOOST_VERSION % 100 
                                                                    << std::endl;
          return 0;
}
```

However when I try to compile it I get the following error:

```
$ g++ boost_version.c 
boost_version.c:1:29: fatal error: boost/version.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

and I'm not sure where I am going wrong. I've looked at the other questions and it doesn't seem to resolve my problems.

Comment: Just guessing here but maybe `/usr/local/include` is not in the preprocessors default header file search path. Have you tried adding the option `-I/usr/local/include`?

Comment: Actually it looks like `boost` isn't even being installed in `/usr/local`

Comment: You *did* run the installation step?

Comment: What step is this exactly? I was under the impression this was the combination of running `bootstrap.sh` and `./b2`

Comment: [Please read the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install).

Comment: Doh! It is `./b2 install`, not just `./b2`

Comment: Is there some specific reason for version 1.59? It might be possible to download boost 1.60 ubuntu source files and then build deb-packages.

Comment: It is the current version of boost that Bitcoin uses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading is hard, I was running

```
./b2
```

instead of

```
./b2 install
```